# "leave others with dying geese" meaning in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> When people fail to respect the P/PC Balance in their use of physical assets in organizations, they decrease organizational effectiveness and often ***leave others with dying geese***.

This is from the book *The 7 Habits of Highly Effective People*. I don't understand what *dying geese* is referring to here. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reference to [the goose that laid the golden eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goose_that_Laid_the_Golden_Eggs). Related idioms include "don't kill the goose that lays the golden eggs".

So this line is saying people who do not respect that "P/PC Balance" thing negatively affects others in the organization and damage the resourcefulness, productivity, and/or effectiveness of the organization which is analogized to the goose that lays the golden eggs.